# How to prevent hiding elements by X in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The problem is that when the screen is reduced, the icons under the graphs will be removed, but this would not be desirable. I also tried to set `zoomEnabled: false`, having previously registered in `zoomType: 'xy'`, it did not help. I also tried to change `labels:` `overflow: "allow", padding: 1`, also without changes. Only reducing the size of the icons helped, but in order for them not to disappear, you need to reduce them very much.

How to make sure that the icons do not disappear on a small screen, or at least only those missing from the chart are hidden (cancellation of adaptation for the X axis)?

Example code for initialization. (Commented out my assumptions):

```
chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
     chart: {
        type: 'column',
        //zoomType: 'xy',
     },
     title: {
        text: 'Title'
     },
     xAxis: {
           categories: $.map(months, function (item) {
               return item;
           }),
           labels: {
               useHTML: true,
               //overflow: "allow",
               //padding: 1,
               fotmatter: function() {
                 let icons = $.map(months, function (item) {
                     let icon = counter;
                     arrayIcon[item] = '<img src="icon_' + item + '.png" height="20">'
                 });

                 let objIcons = Object.assign({}, arrayIcon);
                 return objIcons[this.value];
                },
           },
           //zoomEnabled: false
       },
     yAxis: {
        title: {
           text: 'Sub-title'
        }
     },
     plotOptions: {
            column: {
              states: {
                inactive: {
                    enabled: false
                }
              }
            }
         },
     series: [{
        name: 'Dev #1',
        data: [5, 10, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 40, 80, 90]
     }, {
        name: 'Dev #2',
        data: [15, 15, 18, 40, 30, 25, 60, 60, 80, 70]
     }]
    });
```

In the image, what happens when the screen is reduced
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why labels disappear when resizing the chart is that the number of tick change then.

The solution for always having a fixed number of ticks is setting their positions via `xAxis.tickPositions` or setting `xAxis.tickInterval`.

You can also remove labels when there is no data, by custom code in `labels.formatter()`. This might be use with `responsive.rules`, when you can set a condition on what size of the screen some chart options need to be set.

Here is the example config:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1,
    tickLength: 0,
    labels: {
      overflow: 'allow',
      autoRotation: false,
      useHTML: true,
      formatter: function() {
        return '<img src="' + img_path + '" style=" width:20px; height:20px;" />';
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    data: [1, null, 3, 4]
  }],

  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 200
      },
      chartOptions: {
        xAxis: {
          labels: {
            formatter: function() {
              let txt = '';
              this.chart.series.forEach(series => {
                series.points.forEach(point => {
                  if (point.y === 0 || point.y === null) {
                    if (point.x === this.pos) {
                      return
                    } else {
                      txt += '<img src="' + img_path + '" style=" width:20px; height:20px;" />';
                    }
                  }
                })
              })
              return txt
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ctuL67an/

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules